# problem with react-quill library with next.js project

Tags: next.js, react-quill

I'm running into a weird problem. I'm using NextJS for its server-side rendering capabilities and I am using ReactQuill as my rich-text editor. To get around ReactQuill's tie to the DOM, I'm dynamically importing it. However, that presents another problem which is that when I try to access the component where I'm importing ReactQuill via a anchor link is not working but I can access it via manually hit the route. Here is my directories overview,

```
components/
  crud/
    BlogCreate.js
pages/
  admin/
    crud/
      blog.js
    index.js
  blogs/
    index.js
```

In my `pages/admin/index.js`

```
  ...
    <li className="list-group-item">
      <Link href="/admin/crud/blog">
        <a>Create Blog</a>
      </Link>
    </li>
  ...
```

In my `pages/admin/crud/blog.js`

```
import BlogCreate from "../../../components/crud/BlogCreate";
...
<div className="col-md-12">
  <BlogCreate />
</div>
```

In my `components/crud/BlogCreate.js`

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const ReactQuill = dynamic(() => import("react-quill"), { ssr: false });
import "../../node_modules/react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
...
        <div className="form-group">
          <ReactQuill
            value={body}
            placeholder="Write something amazing..."
            onChange={handleBody}
          />
        </div>
```

in order to use `import "../../node_modules/react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css"` in `components/crud/BlogCreate.js` I use `@zeit/next-css` and here is my `next.config.js`

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
module.exports = withCSS({
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
...
  }
});
```

**Problem**
when I click the `Create Blog` it should be redirect me `http://localhost:3000/admin/crud/blog` but it just freeze.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

But if I manually hit `http://localhost:3000/admin/crud/blog` then it go to the desire page and work perfect.

[image: image3]

[image: image4]

And as soon as I manually load that page then `Create Blog` works. Now I really don't understand where is the problem? Because it show no error that's why I haven't no term to describe my problem that's why I give all the nasty code and directories which I suspect the reason of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give you any solution without seeing the entire project(As you mentioned that **it shows no error**). 
You may remove the `@zeit/next-css` plugin because Next.js 9.3 is [Built-in Sass Support for Global Stylesheets](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#built-in-sass-support-for-global-stylesheets). You can use it for css also.

Create a `pages/_app.js` file if not already present. Then, import the `quill.snow.css` file:

```js
import "../../node_modules/react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";

// This default export is required in a new `pages/_app.js` file.
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

---

If it gives any error then you can create a directory/file to copy-paste the `quill.snow.css` code in that file.

```
pages/
  _app.js
styles/
  quill_style.css
```

Then import the file in `_app.js` like,

```js
import "../styles/styles_quill.css";

// This default export is required in a new `pages/_app.js` file.
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

Eventually you can import your custom gobal css here also.

If although the problem remains then provide your git repository. happy coding ✌️

Comment: Sorry for late response @emonhossain. Yes your second method worked for me. One question how `_app.js` serving those styles to all component of the project? Did it make slow rendering of the other component which didn't need those style at all?

Comment: How to register the react-quill modules in nextjs ?

Answer (score 0):

First: remove your @zeit/next-css setup not needed anymore since next.js version 10.

Second: update nex.js to version 10 you could then use regular import on your modules.

```
import "../../node_modules/react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
```

By the way, I had the same issue with your Nextjs course. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to how I solved this.

```
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.bubble.css";

const ReactQuill = dynamic(
    async () => {
        const { default: RQ } = await import("react-quill");
        return ({ forwardedRef, ...props }) => <RQ ref={forwardedRef} {...props} />;
    },
    {
        ssr: false,
    }
);

const CustomEditor = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const { theme = "snow", height = 150, placeholder = "Write your message...", ...rest } = props;
    return (
        <ReactQuill
            forwardedRef={ref}
            style={{ height: height, marginBottom: "48px" }}
            theme={theme}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            modules={{
                clipboard: {
                    matchVisual: false,
                },
            }}
            {...rest}
        />
    );
});

export default CustomEditor;
```